# How to get subImages from a sprite sheet with different sprite sizes?

Tags: java, image, animation, sprite

I'm doing a fighting game in Java, and I'm having some trouble with the animations.

The thing is when a player is idle or walking, I've no problem because every sprite has a fixed width (50px), but when the player attacks the sprite becomes wider as long as the punch goes further. And in-game the sprite doesn't draw correctly.

PS: I'm saving every frame/sprite inside an arraylist, and I change MAXFRAMES manually depending on the number of sprites.
`SS` is the spritesheet.

I'm using getSubImage method as below.

```
public void setAnimacionIdleRight(BufferedImage ss) {
    this.animation_idle_right = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    BufferedImage tmp = ss.getSubimage(0, 0, 350, 100);
    BufferedImage subtmp = null;
    int k = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < MAXFRAMES; i++) {
        subtmp = tmp.getSubimage((CELLWIDTH * i) + k - CELLWIDTH, 1, CELLWIDTH, CELLHEIGHT);            
        this.animation_idle_right.add(subtmp);
        k++;
    }
}
```

SpriteSheet example:

[image: example]

Any Ideas? Or is the solution brute force img loading?

Comment: Two things: 1- make each sprite the exact same size all the time or 2- Create some kind of lookup table which can tell you the size of the sprite at given position

Comment: @MadProgrammer is absolutely right. There's no other way. I think the second suggestion is best because you'll save space, but there's a lot of overhead involved in creating the LUT. It'll be faster for you to develop if you use the first method.

Comment: Or 3- use some type of image analysis library to separate out sub image rectangles, ones that hold contiguous images... tricky at best.

Comment: Yes, Im trying to loop through the sprite pixels column _(starting in the 'cellwidth' column)_ looking for a pixel RBG != 0, that means the img is wider, and move to the next column until all of them are 0, then set cellwidth with the value of the column, but its very tricky.. =/ If i cant get it done, ill simply crop the sprite manually.

Thank you for your ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

As sugested by MadProgrammer, you can manually set the size of each sprite in the sheet.
Since the height is always the same, then you can simply have an array with the size of the number of sprites on the sheet, and put only sprite width in it.

To help you you could do a loop before manually setting the values like this:

```
float cellWidths[MAX_FRAMES/CELLNUMBER];
for(int i=0; i<MAX_FRAMES/CELLNUMBER;i++){
    cellWidths[i] = CELLWIDTH;
}
//set non default values manually.
```

and then you would only need to change you for like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < MAXFRAMES; i++) {
    subtmp = tmp.getSubimage((cellWidths[i-1] * i) + k - cellWidths[i-1], 1, cellWidths[i-1], CELLHEIGHT);            
    this.animation_idle_right.add(subtmp);
    k++;
}
```

But i may be misunderstanding what MAX_FRAMES mean.